# How to install Java 8 on Kali Nethunter

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, java, jdk, openjdk

Guys I need to install jdk 8 for my programs to work better, many programs do not support the version higher than Java 8 so I want to install Java 8 to run better, I tried to install via `apt-get`, but I saw that it was removed from the Kali repository because very old. Can anyone help me how to install? When I run the command `uname -m` it shows me that the architecture is aarch64 can someone tell me how to install Java 8 on Nethunter for aarch64? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what does `run better` mean? ... what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to download Java 8 so my programs can run better.

Comment: It should be available in the repos. What does `apt search openjdk-8` return?

Comment: @ajgringo619 `Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libreoffice/kali-rolling,unknown 1:7.0.4-3 arm64
  office productivity suite (metapackage)

nvidia-openjdk-8-jre/kali-rolling,unknown 9.+8u272-b10-0+deb9u1~11.2.0-2 amd64
  Obsolete OpenJDK Java runtime, for NVIDIA applications`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download JDK from the [official website](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) (subscription is required) or use the following command:

```
wget -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u281-b09/89d678f2be164786b292527658ca1605/jdk-8u281-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1614342179_659c3e77bffb9a532e2e87404c0c6647
```

then install it:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm
mv 'jdk-8u281-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1614342179_659c3e77bffb9a532e2e87404c0c6647' jdk-8u281-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo tar xvf jdk-8u281-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm
```

Add `java` and `javac` to `update-alternatives`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/bin/java" 100
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/bin/javac" 100
```

set `jdk1.8` as default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/bin/java
```

Check it:

```
java -version
```

sample output:

```
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2):

Guys I managed to solve by adding this line to my sources.list:

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
and then I ran this command:

```
apt-update
```

And then this:

```
apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

And finally this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Then just choose Java 8 and that's it, Java is running :)

Comment: Adding Debian without a pin priority is discouraged.